# Quiero devolver una copia de una matriz pero me devuelve el espacio de memoria de esta. JAVA

Tags: java, bucle-for, matriz

soy nuevo en la programación, entonces me han puesto ha hacer un algoritmo que al introducir una matriz este me devuelva una copia de esta. Pero me devuelve la dirección de memoria.

```
static int[][] copiar_reservas (int[][] reservas) {
        int matriz_nueva[][];
        matriz_nueva = new int [reservas.length][reservas[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i<reservas.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<reservas[i].length; j++) {
                matriz_nueva[i][j] = reservas[i][j];
            }
        }
        return matriz_nueva;
    }
```

PD: No puedo cambiar el encabezado del metodo

Comment: Como estas visualizando la copia del array?

Comment: Hola Sebastian, si usas **System.out.print( matriz );** te devolverá algo como **[[I@5b6f7412**, si quieres ver el contenido de la matriz, debes iterar de la misma forma que usas para hacer la copia.